# I am an Australian on a Tier 2 visa in UK, is a temporary work trip in Paris ok?

Tags: uk-visa

I work in a London office of a company that was bought by a French company. They would like me to go over to Paris for 3 weeks (to meet the team etc).

I am Australian, with a Tier 2 visa.

Will I be contravening any conditions of my Tier 2 working visa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will I be contravening any conditions of my Tier 2 working visa?

No.  Your Tier 2 visa does not prohibit you from making business trips to other jurisdictions.

However, you should be certain that your trip does not violate French immigration law.  As an Australian, you do not need a visa for short-term business visits, but you should be certain that the activities you will be engaging in while in France are permitted for short-term business visitors.